# Perspective Text wont fit in CSS

Tags: html, css, perspective

I have tried absolutely everything to make this text fit the box using CSS perspective. But it literally just wont fit in any form.

My current code:

```
<img src="./img/parcel.png" width="350px">
<div class="centerparcel">
Text on Box Here
</div>
```

.centerparcel:

```
position: absolute;
top: 65%;
left: 37.5%;
width: 285px;
font-size: 25px;
vertical-align: top;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotateY(-30deg) rotateX(0deg);
```

but it just looks cramped and squashed..

[image]

Is there an extra rotate feature that could make this easier, or do I just have to keep trying until I get it right?

Comment: You probably want to add some skewing as well to get the effect right ... And trial&error works best in browser dev tools.

Comment: Skew!!! That worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to CBroe for helping me solve this by commenting, 'add some skewing to get the effect right'.

I never knew skew was a style until now.

My solved code:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%) skewY(8deg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to transform it with `matrix` instead

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/matrix

```
transform: matrix(1,.2,0,1,0,0);
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but it seems more complex to learn than skew.

Comment: @MichaelDavison yeah not as easy to understand as skew